# Can't convert Bytes to UMat when trying to read YUV422 video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to extract frames from a raw video file (YUV422 8 bit coding), but for what I can see, I need to put the data in a `UMat()` but I can't create one with the data from the buffer.
I first convert the data with

`fb = np.frombuffer`

but I'm stuck with how to continue.
If I simply use the new array with

`cv2.cvtColor(um, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422)`

I get `None`, but trying to make the UMat with it I get an error:
`um = cv2.UMat(height, width, cv2.CV_8UC2, db)`

`TypeError: UMat() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`

the complete code:

````
    width = 1824
    height = 942
    pixels_per_frame = width * height
    with open('my_video.1', 'rb') as video:
        header = video.read(16) #passing the initial header info
        while True:
            frame_byte = video.read(pixels_per_frame * 2)
            # print(frame_byte.hex())
            if frame_byte == b"":
                break
            fb = np.frombuffer(frame_byte, dtype=np.uint8)
            um = cv2.UMat(height, width, cv2.CV_8UC2, fb)

            frame = cv2.cvtColor(um , cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422)
            cv2.imshow("Image", frame )
            cv2.waitKey(100) ```
````